# Multiple joins in access, asking for parameter value

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

With the help of a prior article I was able to come up with the following solution for a multi table join for my example of three basic tables I want to join, however I am getting the parameter issue for PRIMARYKEY.

```
select *
FROM       (((
SELECT [PRIMARYKEY] FROM [TABLE 1] 
UNION
SELECT [PRIMARYKEY] FROM [TABLE 2]
UNION
SELECT [PRIMARYKEY] FROM [TABLE 3] )                                                                AS           A
LEFT JOIN  [TABLE 1]      ON    A.[PRIMARYKEY]    =     [TABLE 1].[PRIMARYKEY]               )
LEFT JOIN [TABLE 2]      ON     A.[PRIMARYKEY]     =    [TABLE 2].[PRIMARYKEY]                )
LEFT JOIN [TABLE 3]      ON     A.[PRIMARYKEY]     =    [TABLE 3].[PRIMARYKEY]
```

My idea is to get a full distinct listing of primary keys and then left join to the other tables, as I am aware there are no full joins in access.

Does anyone see something wrong with my script? Is it the "AS A" part that is throwing everything off?

Comment: Just tried in MSAccess - no errors (sure I had to change column and table names). Most likely one of your tables doesn't have column called PRIMARYKEY?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Arvo and @Harvey. I tried it again and it worked. I closed the tables that were open and also closed, without saving, whatever I was working with on the relationships table. I just copied my script above and it worked this time. Not sure if this post still has benefit or if someone can use the script above in the future. Harvey's one below works as well now

Answer (score 1):

Please try this which uses aliases:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM ((( SELECT [PRIMARYKEY] AS MyField
                FROM [TABLE 1]
              UNION
              SELECT [PRIMARYKEY] AS MyField
                FROM [TABLE 2]
              UNION
              SELECT [PRIMARYKEY] AS MyField
                FROM [TABLE 3]
            ) AS A
            LEFT JOIN [TABLE 1]
                   ON A.[MyField] = [TABLE 1].[PRIMARYKEY] 
           )
           LEFT JOIN [TABLE 2]
                  ON A.[MyField] = [TABLE 2].[PRIMARYKEY] 
         )  
         LEFT JOIN [TABLE 3]
                ON A.[MyField] = [TABLE 3].[PRIMARYKEY]
```

You can do Cartesian joins in access (which is how I know full joins).    I often use a one row table called dual to always return one row... (like in oracle).